# What is the second pair of parenthesis in "require('express')()" in node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, frameworks, parentheses

I'm following the socket.io chat application tutorial here - https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

and it's using express framework. There's a code in the tutorial that is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

and if I just use 'require('express')' without the second parenthesis it doesn't work. What does the second parenthesis do and where could I find documentation for the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type returned from `require('express')` is a function. The second set of parenthesis is you actually invoking the function to create an instance of an express app.

It's the equivalent of you doing

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `require('express')` call returns a function and hence you need to call that returned function in order to initialisation an express app. For example, the main entry file of express might look like

```
function one(){/*some code here*/}
function two(){/* some other code here*/ }
Module.exports = one;
```

So essentially what happens is that when you require express the above code is included and the one function is exported for you to use and hence you need to call that function that's why you have that extra parenthesis